# Respectfully show disrespect

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am looking for a word or phrase for behavior that outwardly shows respect while actually showing the reverse - i.e. where every word, tone and action is not actionable as disrespect but the listener knows that that is what is intended.

Comment: sarcasm, satire, or double edge disrespect?

Answer (score 1):

I think [**smarmy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smarmy) is pretty good:

> **1** : revealing or marked by a smug, ingratiating, or false earnestness
>   a tone of *smarmy* self-satisfaction — New Yorker

I generally understand it to be use in a situation where somebody uses *words* or *actions* of respect, but in a tone of voice or mannerism that belies their sincerity. In other words, they are sarcastic about it—and it's obvious that they are mocking the person rather than actually meaning what they say.

Perhaps if they were captured on video or audio, somebody could take them to task (although it would be interpretive if they weren't over the top about it), but if their words were transcribed, they would seem to be spoken in a positive light rather than negative.

Comment: Close but not quite what I am thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend  ***dissimulation***, which means
"concealment of one's thoughts, feelings, or character; pretence."

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissimulation)

Comment: Dissimulation is hiding what you are doing - I am thinking of it being blindingly obvious put also so correct as to be unable to call one out on it.